# Why is png image in video fade out pixelated?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, image, effects

I have used a png image in a video and added a fade out in VSE using the Gamma Cross. I just have another audio layer in the video. See attached images. I am using Blender-Render engine.

[image: Render Settings]

[image: Encoding Settings]

I am attaching three images sequentially fading out. You will notice that towards the fade out end the image starts to pixelate. Why does that happen?

See image state while fading out:

[image: Sate1]

[image: Sate2]

[image: Sate3]

The image has been created in Gimp with following

[image: Properties]

Even on a 200% zoom it does not pixelate.

What should I be doing to avoid the same?

Blend File as requested:

[image]

I can seem to download the blend file. see [image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you possibly post the blend file?

Comment: @Ben Sure. But don't know how I can upload a file. Do you mean like a Link?

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: @Ben apologies for the delay. Kindly find the blend file added to the post. Awaiting insights. Thanks

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but it doesn't seem like the link works.

Comment: @Ben Thats strange, I am being able to download the file. See added screenshot.

Comment: @anand Didn't work for me either yesterday, I can open it but the file is almost empty as if you are using paths in your .blend that go into your local directories and aren't included

Comment: @WhatAMesh Same for me, just downloaded it.

Comment: @anand Could you re-upload your .blend file but this time before uploading go to File>External Data> and click Pack All Into .blend

Comment: @Ben So I have packed the .blend file, couple of times as suggested. Then I got the the msg - "No new files to be packed" . So I am assuming that all's well. Folly of a newbie, kindly bear.

Answer (score 2):

The "Lossless" setting is a variable bitrate value. When the image looses information during a ***fade to black*** the bit rate drops. Change the Output quality to "Constant Bitrate". Place a high value, that retains the quality that you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the resolution. My apologies for the delay in replying. I have uploaded a new blend file - [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6213" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6213/). But the png image is not exported in the film. I am not sure incase its due to the lossless setting. Kindly suggest